# Finding mentioned weekdays from text

Tags: python

Let's say we have a text of

> Even though we celebrate Good Friday and Easter Sunday, there is no mention of days such as "Sunday" or "Wednesday".

Notice the following weekdays are mentioned, `Friday, Sunday, Sunday, Wednesday`

We need output some variable `weekdays` that, in this case, would have:

```
weekdays:    [3,5,7]
```

Assuming,

- We count from 1
- We don't care about repeated entries
- 1 is Monday
- 7 is Sunday

What would be the most Pythonic way to approach such information?

Comment: Please share your attempt. Finding code to parse days of the week should be easy. Then converting those to numbers.

Comment: Right. There can be multiple approaches. Like we can use datetime or regex. It seems like a really simple question, but to have it run optimally, I try to think of the most optimal and Pythonic way to approach this problem

Comment: `the most Pythonic way to approach` - IMO find a method that works; evaluate its effectiveness; fine tune the parts that are problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regular expression to identify the days of the week that appear in the text, and then use a set comprehension to get the desired indices:

```py
days_of_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
day_indices = dict(zip(days_of_week, range(1, 8)))
expr = "|".join(rf"\b{day}\b" for day in days_of_week)
matches = re.findall(expr, text)
result = sorted(list(set(day_indices[day] for day in matches)))

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: This is an amazing implementation, thank you!! Pretty unfortunate that ever-wise moderators decided to close the question, because this answer is a gem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of days and then check for keys by the words in the given text

```
# Dictonary with days as keys and numbers as values
day_dict = {"Monday": 1, "Tuesday": 2, "Wednesday":3 }
text = "Even though we celebrate Good Friday and Easter Sunday, there is no mention of days such as 'Sunday' or 'Wednesday' in the Bible."
res=[]
# loop over words in text
for word in text.split(' '):
    # get dict value based on word
    a = day_dict.get(word)
    # if word exists in dict and is not yet in your "result" --> add it
    if a and a not in res:
        res.append(a)
```